# how to insert unique string into a string builder even if it is a substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i have the below code, and the contents of `self.asStringToCopyFromStatment` is as shown below. the problem i have is, given a row with the following values `4.0   -99 13.07   -99` i it will not be inserted into the string `self.asStringToCopyFromStatment`
because the `in` operator will assume, that it is already exists as it contains the value `44.0 -99 13.07   -99`
i want the strings like:

```
4.0 -99 13.07   -99
-99 19.0    -99 13.9  
0   -99 14.8    -9
```

for example to be inserted into `self.asStringToCopyFromStatment` because they are unique. as long as a particular string is unique i want to add it to `self.asStringToCopyFromStatment`

**code**:

```
def appendDataRow(self):
    row = "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n".format(str(self.getAoC1()),str(self.getAoC2()),str(self.getAvgH1()),str(self.getAvgH2()))
    if (not row in self.asStringToCopyFromStatment()):
        self.inputStringToCopyFromStatement+="{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n".format(str(self.getAoC1()),str(self.getAoC2()),str(self.getAvgH1()),str(self.getAvgH2()))
```

**data/contents of self.inputStringToCopyFromStatement**:

```
51.0    -99 14.26   -99
-99 29.0    -99 13.21
-99 19.0    -99 13.94 #<====================HERE
-99 27.0    -99 14.11
-99 7.0 -99 13.84
-99 3.0 -99 11.25
-99 10.0    -99 11.4
-99 15.0    -99 11.15
23.0    -99 11.43   -99
44.0    -99 13.07   -99 #<====================HERE
85.0    -99 14.66   -99
86.0    -99 14.78   -99
92.0    -99 14.8    -99 #<====================HERE
91.0    -99 14.76   -99
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to check that `row` is indeed found at the beginning of a line:

```
import re

def appendDataRow(self):
    row = "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n".format(str(self.getAoC1()),str(self.getAoC2()),str(self.getAvgH1()),str(self.getAvgH2()))
    if not re.search(rf'^{row}', self.asStringToCopyFromStatment(), re.MULTILINE):
        self.inputStringToCopyFromStatement+="{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n".format(str(self.getAoC1()),str(self.getAoC2()),str(self.getAvgH1()),str(self.getAvgH2()))
```

`^` combined with the flag `re.MULTILINE` matches the beginning of a line.